# How can I switch from legacy editor to new editor in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just did the wrong operation that make the legacy editor as the default editor. Does anyone knows how to set new editor as default? THX

Di

[image]

Comment: I think the new editor is not yet available for your account/domain. Was the new editor available to you and now it is not?

Comment: Yes, the first time when I opened the editor is the newest version but when I click use legacy editor and I don't know how to change it back.

Comment: try going to https://script.google.com and opening it from there. Let us know if that works.

Comment: But regardless of what the issue is now, wait a few days and you will see it. Google announced a transition delay but it will happen as soon as next month.

Comment: Same happens to me and can't find the solution.

Comment: @Chesare there is no solution. You just need to wait until the end of the month and it will appear.

Comment: As of Apr 27, 2021, just click the blue "Use new editor" button.